# DKIM validation

Tags: email

How does `dkim validation` works for google gsuite hosted mail. All the magento notifications goes to spam folder. Have already added the `dkim` provided from gsuite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default maybe is using mail() function, which is not authenticated and is considered spam.

Try install gmailsmtpapp or mageplaza SMTP, next add your SMTP credentials and from now email will be sending authenticated.

Don't forget update SPF records.